# Is there a Minecraft seed with a jungle island and a mushroom island in a warm ocean?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a Minecraft Java Edition 1.16.5 seed with a jungle island and a mushroom island relatively near to each other in a warm ocean?

Comment: yeah, probably. there are alot of seeds, and each seed is bigger than earth.

Comment: Chunkbase is a great tool for finding biomes. Though, I believe you must provide a seed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending how 'relatively near' you want them.

On the seed I play my single-player on, I found a jungle within some 1000 blocks from two mushroom islands, with a warm ocean in between. It's pretty far from spawn though.

The seed is `7995869790344432783`.

[image]

Comment: That is a very good seed! If you know of one where the jungle is an island, that would help even more!

Comment: Sorry, nope. But yeah, the seed is crazy. Two ocean monuments within view from spawn, some truly crazy Shattered Savanna about 1500 blocks south, alongside with a bunch of villages; a huge mesa not that far along the way, a huge jungle with something like 8 temples, ice spikes in the south-east, and so on. But you're probably best off just starting Amidst, highlighting the interesting biomes and start looking through random seeds.

Comment: Or I can use /locate to find the biomes

Comment: By relatively near I mean within 1024 blocks.

Comment: That seed is even better because it has a Modified Jungle Edge!